# Why python multiprocessing async does not call function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm starting using multiprocessing but i have problems with pool because is not calling my function, i can not find which it's wrong in #Case C, other cases works without problems, below my code:

```
import imp
import multiprocessing as mp

mysql_q_mps = imp.load_source('mysql_q_mps', '\\path\\get_query_mps.py')

if __name__ ==  '__main__':

    def get_query_ps(tipo,sql_info,log_filename):
        pool = mp.Pool()      
        cola_logfile=mp.Queue()


        idx_ps = 1

        # Case A, This one works#
        mysql_q_mps.get_query_sps(tipo,sqls_exe,idx_ps,cola_logfile)

        # Case B, This one works#
        cola_1=mp.Process(target=mysql_q_mps.get_query_sps,args=(tipo,sqls_exe,idx_ps,cola_logfile))
        cola_1.start()   

        # Case C, This one does not works#
        pool.apply_async(mysql_q_mps.get_query_sps,(tipo,sqls_exe,idx_ps,cola_logfile)) 

        return    

    log_path='//pathlogfile'
    sqls_exe = 'SQLQuery'

    get_query_ps('exe',sqls_exe,log_path)
```

Comment: Which operating system (Windows is different than unixy systems)? What error do you get?

Comment: Without a [mcve] this is virtually impossible to debug beyond random guessing. But if you want a random guess: You're not waiting for either of these to finish. So, maybe whichever of the two you run first happens to finish whatever you were expecting it to do by the end of the program, but the second one doesn't, so the real difference is that you're running Case C after Case B?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, i was writing my code for test multiprocessing, i've delete case A, Case B, and after Case C i added pool.close and now it works!